# Should Questions regarding Unspecified Tournaments be Closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

In Football/Soccer, There are Four degrees of organization, World > Continental > National > State/District. One example would be FIFA > UEFA > England/Spain/Portugal.

Each National Federation is free to rule its Internal Competetions with whatever rules they wish to enforce. For instance, with Yellow Cards. A question like [1 yellow, 1 red & 1 yellow card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12756/1-yellow-1-red-1-yellow-card) doesn't specify exactly which Tournament it refers to, and as such can have as many answers as Tournaments that exist around the world, simply because it's too broad.

---

However, questions such as [Are there some major cup competitions not using away goals rule?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/are-there-some-major-cup-competitions-not-using-away-goals-rule), while not specifying any competition, it's defined, concise and specific (As one or two examples would suffice).

And, questions like [FIFA World Cup 2014 Tie Breaker Rules: “Between the teams concerned”?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4881/fifa-world-cup-2014-tie-breaker-rules-between-the-teams-concerned), are obviously well scoped and defined.

### These examples would certainly be allowed as they are very well defined, in scope and not too broad.

In sum, should questions regarding rulings and other subjects that differ from Tournament to Tournament be:

a) closed as 'Too Broad';

b) Kept, and answered with all tournaments?

Comment: Welcome. We generally ask for this detail whenever we run into the case in which the answer may be different based on the tournament/league/etc...as shown in the 1 yellow, 1 red, and 1 yellow card question. Beyond that, then it  would be appropriate to place the question on hold as "too broad" if this detail isn't elaborated upon.